# Unknown armature in a kitchen

Tags: plumbing, kitchens

Can someone explain me the function of following armature in a kitchen?

[image: unknown armature with a valve and another thing]

The valve is probably for the dish washer, but what is the purpose
for the metal thing below? It does not seem modifiable and has small
slides near the front cap.

The armature is at a height of about 1.2m in the middle of the kitchen wall.
At a height of about 30cm there are different connections
(water for dish washer and regular kitchen water / wastewater connections).

Comment: It's possible that providing more context might help to suggest an answer. What else is next to or near this thingee in the kitchen? Do you have any way to get an idea of what connections there are/were behind the wall and/or where they lead to?

Comment: @irrationalJohn I extended the question. Unfortunately, I do not know what is inside/behind the wall. I am quite sure, that it is related with the dish washer water supply.

Comment: Is this in a house, or something else (RV, boat, etc.)? Location might also be helpful

Comment: Can you take a better picture and maybe tape a ruler or a USA dime next to it?  A side view would not be amiss either.  ... Is it above a counter? Or is it open wall about man height?  It may be a fancy shutoff valve for an optional icemaker or coffee/tea machine (if there is a countertop directly below it).

Comment: @BrockAdams Thanks for all the suggestion, meanwhile I found out its purpose (see my answer below).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The armature is indeed a valve for the dishwasher or washing machine.
The unknown part of it is a **ventilation** which serves as a non-return device.

It avoids that (possibly dirty) water is sucked back into the general fresh water supply, if there is a pressure drop into the "negative region"
due to some defects or interruption.

Answer (score 2):

I highly doubt this is a valve for the dishwasher. Since this is above the countertop (which I'm assuming since there's tile on the wall), it may be a pot filler with the end capped off.

Answer (score 1):

In some places they are called "air gaps" and they do what jofel said, they prevent dirty water from being pulled out of the drain into the dishwasher.